# Stuck with kernel 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: upgrade, kernel, lvm, 23.10

I'm running Ubuntu on a thin client as a headless home server. I've upgraded to 23.10 a few monthes ago, but I realize I've been stuck with kernel 6.2.0 since then.

Running **sudo apt update**, **sudo apt upgrade** or **sudo apt dist-upgrade** gets me nothing (everything seems to be up to date).

Running **lsb_release -a** gets me

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:        23.10
Codename:       mantic
```

So I'm certain I'm on 23.10.

I'm fairly new to linux so I'm not sure what to do, I'm sorry ^^'.

---

**Edit 1 :**
As mentioned in a comment, I did

```
sudo apt-mark auto `apt-mark showmanual | grep linux`
```

And afterwards **apt-update** and **apt-upgrade**, but nothing.
What's even more strange is that my /boot/grub/ only mentions things like

> linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro
> initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic

Nothing related to 6.2.0 kernel is in there.
Ubuntu is the only OS installed on the machine.

**uname -r** still outputs *6.2.0-35-generic*.

---

**Edit 2 :**
Running **sudo update-grub** and then rebooting, **sudo apt-update** and **sudo apt-upgrade** tell me everything is up to date, and **uname -a** stills stays :

> Linux 6.2.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Oct  3 13:14:56 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

For reference, here is the content of my /boot/grub/grub.cfg : https://pastebin.com/snBWFJUA
Strangely enough, everything is related to kernel 6.5 and in /boot I only have those files :

```
config-6.5.0-25-generic
initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic
System.map-6.5.0-25-generic
vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic
```

**Edit 3 :**
Full **boot-repair** report as requested : https://pastebin.com/DQqRtG2q

Comment: In a terminal, (crtl+alt+t to start one) run apt-mark showmanual and see if the linux kernel packages are shown.  If they are, just use apt-mark to set them to "auto", and try the update/upgrade again.

Comment: In a terminal, run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. If there are any errors in either, then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506623/edit) to show the complete output of both.

Comment: @ubfan1 I don't see anything named "kernel" in the apt-mark showmanual results.
However I do have 
linux-generic
linux-image-generic

Is that related?
I've never used apt-mark.

Comment: Is this a dual boot system?  Does another OS control the booting?  ie. maybe the other OS needs to update it's bootloader using its equivalent of `update-grub` so it will detect the newer 6.5 kernels & update its bootloader to offer that instead.  (*I can't see a held kernel allowing release-upgrade.. thus this alternative*)

Comment: @user68186 I edited my question with the new things I tried according to comments. Still same situation. Strange.

Comment: Is the running system perhaps an install media?  With persistence, you may update kernels, but the boot process totally ignores those new kernels, and uses the original one which is not in your /boot.

Comment: @user68186 I ran update-grub, same result. I copy/pasted my grub.cfg in my edit 2 on my original message if you want to take a look. I'm at a complete loss !

Comment: @ubfan1 nope, not an install media. Ubuntu is the sole OS installed on a Lenovo ThinkCenter M910q thin PC. I use it as a home server.

Comment: I am stumped! I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @user68186 haha thank you for trying anyway !

Comment: Added the lvm tag since that might explain things, and others who use lvm might chip in. A full boot-repair report might help clear things up too, don't run anything, just get the report and post a link.

Comment: @ubfan1 you'll find the "boot-repair" report in my edit 3. There ARE indeed references to the old kernel here (finally !). It looks like I may have a bit of partition crap going on but I don't know what to make of it honestly.

Comment: Your system is a legacy boot, on a gpt disk, with partitions for 1)bios-grub, 2)boot, and 3)logical group for root and home.  Search this site for grub lvm boot  -- I don't use logical volumes, so cannot offer any advice, but maybe your issue is as simple as not mounting the /boot partition 2 in your lvm root (so updates go there).  Maybe first fill up the /boot partition with contents of the root's /boot?

Comment: @ubfan1 sorry for the long delay I was unavailable. So, your were partially right and put me on the right track. Grub was actually booting from the /boot partition... which was not mounted on Ubuntu ! So, when I was running sudo upgrade, my boot directory in Ubuntu was updated, but it was an unused directory ! 
The solution was as simple as mounting the boot partition as /boot.
I then ran sudo upgrade, and voila ! Stupidly simple... Thank you ! :)

Do you want to post a new reply so that I can accept it as the answer? Otherwise I will do it myself.

Comment: Go ahead and answer, you can put in more details than I could, so might be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My computer was separated in 3 partitions : 1- bios/grub, 2- boot files, 3- ubuntu.

For some reason, my boot partition got unmounted in Ubuntu so it wasn't recognized. When I was trying to update using apt upgrade, Ubuntu put the files in a boot folder in its own partition (the third one).

However, since Grub was booting from the files located in the Boot partition (the 2nde one), any files updated in the boot folder of the ubuntu partition was ignored.

I simply had to remount the boot partition as /boot in Ubuntu and voila !

Many thanks to @ubfan1 and others for their help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then, and only then, should you run:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

The first command, `sudo apt update`, updates the list of packages that need to be updated (it checks for available updates). Without updating the package list, your system will never know which packages are or are not out of date.

Therefore, we should always run `sudo apt update` at least once per day, before running any other `apt` commands to install or upgrade packages.

Comment: I should have wrote it but yes, I already regularly do an apt update. 
sudo apt update : everything is up to date
sudo apt upgrade : same
sudo apt dist-upgrade : same

Still, no kernel update :x.

Comment: Okay, then run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic`

Comment: If and when you reboot, the newest kernel should be selected by default, but go ahead and manually select the newest kernel from the grub menu instead if it still boots to the old one. If only the older kernel version is shown on the grub menu advanced options, then run `sudo update-grub` after you boot up and then reboot and if it's still the same, then you should reinstall grub to the correct disk partition which can vary depending on your setup.

Comment: Bootrepair might be an option if you don't feel like looking that stuff up.

Comment: I ran sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic and then rebooted. Nothing changed. I updated grub as you and another commenter said. You can take a look at my grub.cfg in the second edit of my original post.
I really can't understand what's happening ^^'

Comment: @Mysterius So which kernel did you select from the grub menu?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, I noticed my Ubuntu 23.10 VM wasn't updating kernels either -- all the other expected updates were working.  Take a look at the manual settings:

```
apt-mark showmanual | grep linux
```

If you are getting entries like linux-image-generic-14, then that explains why they are not getting updates.

Set them back to "auto":

```
sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-mark showmanual | grep linux)
```

(or just cut and paste from your previous apt-mark output).

Then do the

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and you should be getting the new kernels too.

Comment: I did that, and it indeed found some things like linux-image-generic. After your commands those results did not appear anymore, but an update or upgrade changed nothing, neither did reboot in :(.